# Could I change my old Apple ID for when I do updates on my Mac?

Tags: high-sierra

I've got a mac Mini 2014 that works wonderfully.  I've got this little issue that when I need to do the macOS updates it prompts me for my old Apple ID that I use no more.
Now I'm using a newer Apple ID for both iCloud Preferences and the App Store.
Is there any way to get rid of this old Apple ID and use just the new one for updates too?

I'd appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: You'd need to nuke & pave, so the Mac 'belongs' to the new ID & abandon any apps that were purchased with the old one, too... but it prompts me to ask - why did you abandon the old ID? That was always going to become an issue in the future.

Comment: that's horrible, do I really need to wipe and install just for that?.  I stopped using the old email I used for my Apple ID for some reasons.. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It would have been simpler to change the primary email address associated with the old ID... & yes, to remove it, it's nuke & pave, with no restore from Time Machine, except piecemeal for docs etc.